# FFMPEG Getting Error During Segmenting MP4 Video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

I am getting below error while I am breaking an `MP4` video into small segments, using below command.

```
ffmpeg -i F:\video_data_set\non-profit-in-funnel-scripts.mp4 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_start_number 1 -codec copy -copyts -avoid_negative_ts 1 F:\video_data_set\test\%d_4k_compressed.mp4
```

[image: Please see FFMPEG error during segment command]

Comment: Add `-map 0:v -map 0:a`